# UITableView freezing cells. How to solve it?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have `tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath` function:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell: ProjectCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("Cell") as! ProjectCell
  let rightUtilityButtons = NSMutableArray()
  rightUtilityButtons.sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor(UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 200.0/255.0, blue: 122.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), icon: UIImage(named: "ic_edit"))
  rightUtilityButtons.sw_addUtilityButtonWithColor(UIColor(red: 255.0/255.0, green: 120.0/255.0, blue: 122.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0), icon: UIImage(named: "ic_close"))
  cell.setRightUtilityButtons(rightUtilityButtons as [AnyObject], withButtonWidth: 70)
  cell.delegate = self

  let project = projects[indexPath.row] as! Project
  cell.projectNameLabel.text = project.name
  cell.projectDescriptionLabel.text = project.desc
  cell.projectDateLabel.text = project.duedate 

  cell.customView.backgroundColor = getColor(indexPath.row * 10)
  cell.backView.layer.cornerRadius = 6
  cell.backView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
  cell.backView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
  cell.backView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5   

  return cell
}
```

And Problem is here:

```
cell.backView.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
cell.backView.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
cell.backView.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
```

Without this code, my table view works great. How to solve this problem. Maybe better place for my cell view will be willDisplayCell, but how to put this code there?

Comment: Use an image instead that you can stretch, as shadows on the layer don't work great in tableview's as they must be redrawn each frame.

Comment: You have your own custom ProjectCell. Why don't you put shadow related code in that file. (I mean in some initialization function)

Comment: You mean to add shadow in background image file? Or add my shadow to ProjectCell file?

Comment: I add my shadow in awakeFromNib and still freezing.

Comment: override initWithCoder and add shadowColor,shadowOffset and shadowOpacity in it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try next things to improve shadow performance:

1. Move shadow initialization to cell's initialization methods.
2. Rasterize your layer, using `shouldRasterize` property of `CALayer` (also you should set `rasterizationScale` property to `UIScreen.mainScreen().scale`)
3. Use `shadowPath` property of `CALayer` instead `shadowOffset`, like this:

_

```
var shadowBounds = self.bounds
shadowBounds = CGRectOffset(shadowBounds, -1, 1)
let cornerRadius = 6
layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: shadowBounds, cornerRadius: cornerRadius).CGPath
```

As an alternative way you can use resizable transparent image below your cell.

Comment: Works without freezing but I have too much black color on the right. How to solve it?

Comment: Just set different offset of shadowBounds.

Answer (score 1):

1. Move the code you are setting the shadow to cell's **initialization**. Right now, the shadow is set every time delegate returns cell to the table view. You don't have to do this for cells that are just being reused and already have shadow configured.
2. Remember to set `shadowPath` when dealing with shadows. It improves performance.

   ```
   [view.layer setShadowPath:[[UIBezierPath  bezierPathWithRect:view.bounds] CGPath]];
   ```